# Typescript infers the wrong return of a method?

Tags: typescript, types, monads, type-inference, option-type

I have been trying to make a sort of Monadic wrapper for Data fetched from an API. I want it to have 4 shapes:

- Initial (I haven't written this one yet)
- Loading
- Failed
- Loaded

This is a snippet of my implementation.

```js
type Data<A> = Failed<A> | Loaded<A> | Loading<A>

export class Loaded<A> {
  readonly kind: "Loaded" = "Loaded"

  constructor(public readonly value: A) {}
  map<B>(f: (a: A) => B): Data<B> {
    return loaded(f(this.value))
  }

  chain<B>(f: (a: A) => Data<B>): Data<B> {
    return f(this.value)
  }

  flatMap<B>(f: (a: A) => Data<B[]>): Data<B>[] {
    const result = f(this.value)
    switch(result.kind) {
      case 'Failed':
        return []

      case 'Loading':
        return []

      case 'Loaded':
        const elements = result.value
        const loadedElements = elements.map(loaded)
        return loadedElements
    }
  }

  /* ... some type guards ... */

  public match<O1, O2, O3>({
    loading,
    loaded,
    failed,
  }: {
    loading: (percent: number) => O1,
    loaded: (value: A) => O2,
    failed: (error: any) => O3,
  }):O2 {
    return loaded(this.value)
  }
}

export class Failed<A> {
  readonly kind: "Failed" = "Failed"
  constructor(public readonly error: any = undefined) {}

  map<B>(f: (a: A) => B): Data<B> {
    return failed(this.error)
  }

  chain<B>(f: (a: A) => Data<B>): Data<B> {
    return failed(this.error)
  }

  flatMap<B>(f: (a: A) => Data<B[]>): Data<B>[] {
    return []
  }

  /* ... some type guards ... */

  public match<O1, O2, O3>({
    loading,
    loaded,
    failed,
  }: {
    loading: (percent: number) => O1,
    loaded: (value: A) => O2,
    failed: (error: any) => O3,
  }):O3 {
    return failed(this.error)
  }
}

export class Loading<A> {
  readonly kind: "Loading" = "Loading"

  constructor(public readonly percent: number = 0) {}

  map<B>(f: (a: A) => B): Data<B> {
    return loading()
  }

  chain<B>(f: (a: A) => Data<B>): Data<B> {
    return loading()
  }

  flatMap<B>(f: (a: A) => Data<B[]>): Data<B>[] {
    return []
  }

  /* ... some type guards ... */

  public match<O1, O2, O3>({
    loading,
    loaded,
    failed,
  }: {
    loading: (percent: number) => O1,
    loaded: (value: A) => O2,
    failed: (error: any) => O3,
  }):O1 {
    return loading(this.percent)
  }
}

// helper functions
const failed = <A>(error?: any):Data<A> =>  new Failed<A>(error)
const loaded = <A>(value: A):Data<A> => new Loaded<A>(value)
const loading = <A>():Data<A> => new Loading<A>()

const maybe = <A>(value?: A):Data<A> => value === undefined ? failed() : loaded(value)
```

I have test the map, flatMap and chain methods and they seem to work as intented (both in types and runtime behaviour)

I want to have a `match` function that runs a function based on what variant of Data it is. So if the monad is in the `failed` state it would run the `failed` callback, if `loaded` then runs the `loaded` function etc...

I have made sure to make the function have 4 generic outputs `O1, O2, O3, O4` and to explicitly annotate the return type (although typescript should be able to infer it rather easily.

The problem appears here:

```
const data = maybe(3)

const x = data.match({
  loaded: () => 'string',
  loading: () => [],
  failed: () => 3,
})
x // <-- content is 'string' but when type says number
```

It is inferring x wrong saying it is of type number when it should know that data is of the type `Loaded`. Or am I wrong?

How can I make this work?

Also *please* let me know if there is a better way of building such a monad in Typescript without sacrificing type-safety (possibly even improving it, why not!)

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have syntax for Monads, so you need to always wrpa your data to the Container. The merhod match should return Data<...>.

Comment: Look at Promises and async/await sugar

Comment: are you sure that the behavior that your looking isn't already available from the future/task/async adt? (implemented in fluture, crocks and ramda-fantasy). If you need to know the percent loaded maybe the stream adt is appropriate. Is this the only way you have available to handle having your program handle a loading state?

Answer (score 0):

Look at inerred types for maybe, data, match

```
const maybe: <A>(value?: A) => Data<A>
const data: Data<number>
(method) match<any[], string, number>({ loading, loaded, failed, }: { loading: (percent: number) => any[]; loaded: (value: number) => string; failed: (error: any) => number; }): number
```

You chould define veriable "data" as Loaded<>

```
const data2 = new Loaded(3);
// const x2: string
const x2 = data2.match({
  loaded: () => 'string',
  loading: () => [],
  failed: () => 3,
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Data%3CA%3E%20%3D%20Failed%3CA%3E%20%7C%20Loaded%3CA%3E%20%7C%20Loading%3CA%3E%0A%0Aexport%20class%20Loaded%3CA%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20readonly%20kind%3A%20%22Loaded%22%20%3D%20%22Loaded%22%0A%0A%20%20constructor(public%20readonly%20value%3A%20A)%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20map%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20B)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20loaded(f(this.value))%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20chain%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20Data%3CB%3E)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20f(this.value)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20flatMap%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20Data%3CB%5B%5D%3E)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20f(this.value)%0A%20%20%20%20switch(result.kind)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'Failed'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'Loading'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'Loaded'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20elements%20%3D%20result.value%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20loadedElements%20%3D%20elements.map(loaded)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20loadedElements%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%2F*%20...%20some%20type%20guards%20...%20*%2F%0A%0A%20%20public%20match%3CO1%2C%20O2%2C%20O3%3E(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20loading%2C%0A%20%20%20%20loaded%2C%0A%20%20%20%20failed%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20loading%3A%20(percent%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20O1%2C%0A%20%20%20%20loaded%3A%20(value%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20O2%2C%0A%20%20%20%20failed%3A%20(error%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20O3%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%3AO2%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20loaded(this.value)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20class%20Failed%3CA%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20readonly%20kind%3A%20%22Failed%22%20%3D%20%22Failed%22%0A%20%20constructor(public%20readonly%20error%3A%20any%20%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%7D%0A%0A%20%20map%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20B)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20failed(this.error)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20chain%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20Data%3CB%3E)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20failed(this.error)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20flatMap%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20Data%3CB%5B%5D%3E)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%2F*%20...%20some%20type%20guards%20...%20*%2F%0A%0A%20%20public%20match%3CO1%2C%20O2%2C%20O3%3E(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20loading%2C%0A%20%20%20%20loaded%2C%0A%20%20%20%20failed%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20loading%3A%20(percent%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20O1%2C%0A%20%20%20%20loaded%3A%20(value%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20O2%2C%0A%20%20%20%20failed%3A%20(error%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20O3%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%3AO3%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20failed(this.error)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20class%20Loading%3CA%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20readonly%20kind%3A%20%22Loading%22%20%3D%20%22Loading%22%0A%0A%20%20constructor(public%20readonly%20percent%3A%20number%20%3D%200)%20%7B%7D%0A%0A%20%20map%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20B)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20loading()%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20chain%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20Data%3CB%3E)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20loading()%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20flatMap%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20Data%3CB%5B%5D%3E)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%2F*%20...%20some%20type%20guards%20...%20*%2F%0A%0A%20%20public%20match%3CO1%2C%20O2%2C%20O3%3E(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20loading%2C%0A%20%20%20%20loaded%2C%0A%20%20%20%20failed%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20loading%3A%20(percent%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20O1%2C%0A%20%20%20%20loaded%3A%20(value%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20O2%2C%0A%20%20%20%20failed%3A%20(error%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20O3%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%3AO1%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20loading(this.percent)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20helper%20functions%0Aconst%20failed%20%3D%20%3CA%3E(error%3F%3A%20any)%3AData%3CA%3E%20%3D%3E%20%20new%20Failed%3CA%3E(error)%0Aconst%20loaded%20%3D%20%3CA%3E(value%3A%20A)%3AData%3CA%3E%20%3D%3E%20new%20Loaded%3CA%3E(value)%0Aconst%20loading%20%3D%20%3CA%3E()%3AData%3CA%3E%20%3D%3E%20new%20Loading%3CA%3E()%0A%0Aconst%20maybe%20%3D%20%3CA%3E(value%3F%3A%20A)%3A%20Data%3CA%3E%20%3D%3E%20value%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined%20%3F%20failed()%20%3A%20loaded(value)%0A%0Aconst%20data%20%3D%20maybe(3)%0A%0Aconst%20x%20%3D%20data.match(%7B%0A%20%20loaded%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20'string'%2C%0A%20%20loading%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%5B%5D%2C%0A%20%20failed%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%203%2C%0A%7D)%0A%0A%0Aconst%20data2%20%3D%20new%20Loaded(3)%3B%0A%2F%2F%20const%20x2%3A%20string%0Aconst%20x2%20%3D%20data2.match(%7B%0A%20%20loaded%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20'string'%2C%0A%20%20loading%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%5B%5D%2C%0A%20%20failed%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%203%2C%0A%7D))

Comment: The question is (at least for me) why the inferred return type for `match<any[], string, number>` is `number`.

Comment: It looks like the compiler picks method signature from first type from union Failed<A> | Loaded<A> | Loading<A>

Answer (score 0):

> "when it should know that data is of the type Loaded."

It shouldn't, because your return type for `maybe` is `Data<A>`, so the inferred type for `data` is `Data<number>`. However, I'd expect the inferred type to be the union of return types for the 3 cases: `number | string | any[]`, or maybe to report an error. Instead it seems to pick the return type from the first option (if you change to `type Data<A> = Loading<A> | Failed<A> | Loaded<A>` you'll see `x`'s type change). I don't see a good reason for this behavior, it might even be a bug.

Using `kind` as described in discriminated unions documentation fixes the problem:

```
function match<A, O1, O2, O3>(data: Data<A>, matcher: {
    loading: (percent: number) => O1,
    loaded: (value: A) => O2,
    failed: (error: any) => O3,
  }) { 
    switch (data.kind) {
        case "Failed": return data.match(matcher)
        case "Loaded": return data.match(matcher)
        case "Loading": return data.match(matcher)
    }
}

const y = match(data, {
  loaded: () => 'string',
  loading: () => [],
  failed: () => 3,
})
```

`y`'s type is shown [on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Data%3CA%3E%20%3D%20Failed%3CA%3E%20%7C%20Loaded%3CA%3E%20%7C%20Loading%3CA%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Loaded%3CA%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20readonly%20kind%3A%20%22Loaded%22%20%3D%20%22Loaded%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(public%20readonly%20value%3A%20A)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20map%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20B)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20loaded(f(this.value))%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20chain%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20Data%3CB%3E)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20f(this.value)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20flatMap%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20Data%3CB%5B%5D%3E)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20f(this.value)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20switch(result.kind)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'Failed'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'Loading'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'Loaded'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20elements%20%3D%20result.value%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20loadedElements%20%3D%20elements.map(loaded)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20loadedElements%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F*%20...%20some%20type%20guards%20...%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20public%20match%3CO1%2C%20O2%2C%20O3%3E(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loading%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loaded%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20failed%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loading%3A%20(percent%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20O1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loaded%3A%20(value%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20O2%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20failed%3A%20(error%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20O3%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%3AO2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20loaded(this.value)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Failed%3CA%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20readonly%20kind%3A%20%22Failed%22%20%3D%20%22Failed%22%0D%0A%20%20constructor(public%20readonly%20error%3A%20any%20%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20map%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20B)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20failed(this.error)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20chain%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20Data%3CB%3E)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20failed(this.error)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20flatMap%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20Data%3CB%5B%5D%3E)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F*%20...%20some%20type%20guards%20...%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20public%20match%3CO1%2C%20O2%2C%20O3%3E(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loading%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loaded%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20failed%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loading%3A%20(percent%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20O1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loaded%3A%20(value%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20O2%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20failed%3A%20(error%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20O3%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%3AO3%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20failed(this.error)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Loading%3CA%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20readonly%20kind%3A%20%22Loading%22%20%3D%20%22Loading%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(public%20readonly%20percent%3A%20number%20%3D%200)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20map%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20B)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20loading()%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20chain%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20Data%3CB%3E)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20loading()%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20flatMap%3CB%3E(f%3A%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20Data%3CB%5B%5D%3E)%3A%20Data%3CB%3E%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F*%20...%20some%20type%20guards%20...%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20public%20match%3CO1%2C%20O2%2C%20O3%3E(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loading%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loaded%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20failed%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loading%3A%20(percent%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20O1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loaded%3A%20(value%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20O2%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20failed%3A%20(error%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20O3%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%3AO1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20loading(this.percent)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20helper%20functions%0D%0Aconst%20failed%20%3D%20%3CA%3E(error%3F%3A%20any)%3AData%3CA%3E%20%3D%3E%20%20new%20Failed%3CA%3E(error)%0D%0Aconst%20loaded%20%3D%20%3CA%3E(value%3A%20A)%3AData%3CA%3E%20%3D%3E%20new%20Loaded%3CA%3E(value)%0D%0Aconst%20loading%20%3D%20%3CA%3E()%3AData%3CA%3E%20%3D%3E%20new%20Loading%3CA%3E()%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20maybe%20%3D%20%3CA%3E(value%3F%3A%20A)%3AData%3CA%3E%20%3D%3E%20value%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined%20%3F%20failed()%20%3A%20loaded(value)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20data%20%3D%20maybe(3)%0D%0Aconst%20x%20%3D%20data.match(%7B%0D%0A%20%20loaded%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20'string'%2C%0D%0A%20%20loading%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20failed%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%203%2C%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0Ax%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20match%3CA%2C%20O1%2C%20O2%2C%20O3%3E(data%3A%20Data%3CA%3E%2C%20matcher%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loading%3A%20(percent%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20O1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loaded%3A%20(value%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20O2%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20failed%3A%20(error%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20O3%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20switch%20(data.kind)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20%22Failed%22%3A%20return%20data.match(matcher)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20%22Loaded%22%3A%20return%20data.match(matcher)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20%22Loading%22%3A%20return%20data.match(matcher)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20y%20%3D%20match(data%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20loaded%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20'string'%2C%0D%0A%20%20loading%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20failed%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%203%2C%0D%0A%7D)) as `string | number | any[]` as expected.